# Multiple correlation in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation, multicollinearity

Consider the following dataset I want to use as the independent variables to conduct linear regression on:

```
set.seed(42)
sa = runif(10)
sb = runif(10)
sc = sb+sa
sd = sb-sa
df = data.frame(sa,sb,sc,sd)
```

Now I want to perform tests for multicollinearity. I'm aware of the `ppcor` package, which calculates the partial correlation between the variables. In this case:

```
> pcor(df)
$estimate
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  1.00000000  0.06649968 -0.7325597  0.7706902
[2,]  0.06649968  1.00000000 -0.6304810 -0.6870502
[3,] -0.73255975 -0.63048097  1.0000000  0.1308260
[4,]  0.77069021 -0.68705016  0.1308260  1.0000000
```

As far as I know, there is no way of telling that `sc` and `sd` are linear combinations of `sa` and `sb`, just by looking at the estimates (or the other outputs of `pcor`, for that matter).

The only method that comes to my mind, is applying linear regression on each of the independent variables like so:

```
summary(lm(sc~sa+sb,df))

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.404e-16  3.915e-17 3.587e+00   0.0089 ** 
sa          1.000e+00  4.716e-17 2.121e+16   <2e-16 ***
sb          1.000e+00  4.135e-17 2.418e+16   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.672e-17 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 

summary(lm(sd~sa+sb,df))

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.404e-16  3.915e-17 3.587e+00   0.0089 ** 
sa          1.000e+00  4.716e-17 2.121e+16   <2e-16 ***
sb          1.000e+00  4.135e-17 2.418e+16   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.672e-17 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1
```

I'm wondering two things:

1. Is my approach with linear regression reasonable? I think the downside is, that it can only detect linear correlation. But non-linear correlation shouldn't be a problem with linear regression, right?
2. Is there an R function/package that automatically checks for multiple correlation?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean specifically by "non-linear correlation" and "multiple correlation"?  I suspect different readers might have different understandings of these terms.  If by "multiple correlation" you mean collinearity (or approximate collinearity), then--as you note--`lm` automatically checks for this.  Have you investigated the capabilities of `influence.measures`?  You might also want to look at the output of `svd`.

Comment: By _non-linear correlation_ I mean relationships like `y = x²` which can for example be measured by Spearman's correlation coefficient. For _multiple correlation_ I would propose wikipedia's definition: The highest (linear) correlation between `y` and the best linear combination of the `x_i`. I guess it's the same as _collinearity_, except that I only heard of _collinearity_ in the field of regression analysis as a problematic property (whereas I think the term _multiple correlation_ sounds more like a general statistical property).

Comment: I've never heard of the `influence.measures` tool suite or to apply `svd` in regression diagnostics. Especially the former might be interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You got a warning when doing the `lm` estimation. That shows a problem:

```
Warning message:
In summary.lm(lm1 <- lm(sc ~ sa + sb, df)) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

You could try `vif` and `alias` to identify the linear combination:

```
yy<-runif(10)
summary(lm2<-lm(yy~sc+sa+sb,df))

library(car)
vif(lm1)
      sa       sb 
1.004442 1.004442 
Warning message:
In summary.lm(object) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
vif(lm2)
Error in vif.default(lm2) : there are aliased coefficients in the model
alias( lm2 )
Model :
yy ~ sc + sa + sb

Complete :
   (Intercept) sc sa
sb  0           1 -1
```

Comment: It says summary _may_ be unreliable. It shouldn't be, though, because the linear model is in fact a perfect fit. Your vif and alias output confirms that, right?

Comment: VIF appears to be almost exactly the approach I described in my question. One question though: Why do we need to pass a linear model to the `vif`-function when it only needs the independent variables? It literally doesn't matter what I enter as the dependent variable in the linear model, `vif` returns the same results. The VIF-formula states the same. The R documentation does not address this.

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating correlation with collinearity. They are not the same. You can have high correlation and no problematic collinearity and you can have high collinearity with no high correlation.

In R there is the perturb package that lets you check the condition indexes of a multiple regression and also lets you look at collinearity by adding noise to the independent variables many times and checking how that noise affects the parameter estimates.

Comment: Could you give a short example, where two variables are collinear but not linearly correlated? To me, those two were the same. [Zuur](http://iis4.nateko.lu.se/courses/ngem01/ZuurEtAl_2010_Stistics.pdf) for example states "Collinearity is the existence of
correlation between covariates". I'll look into perturn in the meantime.

Comment: You would need more than two variables.  If there are only 2 IVs, then you are right. But e.g. with 10 IVs, just let 9 of them be independent and the tenth be the sum of the other 9.  All correlations will be low, but there is perfect colinearity.

Comment: That's why I was using the term _multiple correlation_ (although not consistently). In your example my approach (that appears to be congruent with VIF) would find perfect collinearity. To summarize: _multiple correlation_ and _(multi-)collinearity_ describe the same concept and measure to what degree a variable is the linear combination of other variables, correct?

Comment: No. Multiple correlation, in my opinion, is a term that shouldn't be used - it's confusing.  It refers to R^2 in a regression equation whereas regular correlation is a relationship among 2 variables with no dependent variable.  Collinearity is a relationship among the independent variables and there is no dependent variable.

Comment: Let `X` be the set of independent variables and `X_i` the i-th independent variable: If you calculate the R^2 for 'i' models, where the dependent variable is each `X_i` and the independent variables are `X` without `X_i`. Then, which are you measuring, multiple correlation or multicollinearity (or does it depend on the viewpoint)? In my understanding, each R^2 measures the linear dependency of `X_i` from all other variables, thus collinearity. How else would you suggest testing for multicollinearity (which is what I originally intended)? The VIF, which is often suggested, relies on the R^2.

Comment: You should test for collinearity using collinearity diagnostics like the condition index; the condition index is better than VIF.  If you have categorical variables, perturb can be useful. Your way would involve i regressions and I am not sure it is even equivalent to VIF